# form validation using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to validate a sample form. I need the "name" section not to start with digit. If the name starts with digit then it'll show error...how do I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <script src="js/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);
$(document).ready(function(){
$('pre').addClass('prettyprint linenums');
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-22151549-3']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +   '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];   s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();
 </script>
 <body>
  <form action="" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal">
  <label class="" for="name">Your Name</label>                          
  <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name" id="name" >
  <br/>

  <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
  <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="email" id="email">
  <br/>

<label class="control-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="subject" id="subject">
<br/>

<label class="control-label" for="message">Your Message</label>
<textarea class="input-xlarge" name="message" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
 <br/>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Submit</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use regular expression validation

Comment: do you have any online tutorial for that?

Comment: Why are you insisting that names do not begin with a number? http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Quentin That was a laugh!

Comment: @Quentin Added you in the answer, if you like it?!?

Comment: @Quentin Ok, you put that up!?! However, answer changed! (Actually you are right, no place to promote sarcasm right?)

Comment: @Quentin The text was from the first comment of Peter btw, not that I invented *that* up!

Comment: There's a subtle difference between "Here are some examples of people who might have a name like this" and "You must be one of these kinds of people if you have a name like this".

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, yeah I see, the laughter carried me away (too little place to put *all*, right?). However I am into thinking if I might ask you kindly to reconsider the downvote, just to make it not look like it "does not work". Maybe?

Comment: You're assuming that the person who downvoted the answer and the person who criticised it are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using html5 doctype, do the below.

replace `<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name" id="name" >`

with this

`<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name" id="name" pattern="^[^0-9].*" title="Cannot start with digit" />`

This will work. This will also alert the user. You don't need to do anything.

Mark it as answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//returns number at the beginning or NAN
var validate = parseInt(formData);  

//if there was a number in front of the string, still the number
//if there was a NaN, this returns NaN
validate = +validate                

if (validate || validate === 0) {
  alert('Not a name!')
}
```

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function()
{
    var str;
    $('#name').change(function()
    {
    str = ('#name').val();
    if(!isNaN(str[0])
    {
         alert('error') //of course you should change the error message ;)
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Will return true `isNaN('13abc') -> true` as in console!

Comment: but it's str[0] so it must be only one character ;)